# connect TI msp430 CC3200 and android app to azure

Tags: android, azure, cloud, msp430, texas-instruments

i'd like to know if it is possible to connect to the very same cloud system(or a database), azure, a msp430 with wifi module cc3200 and a android app.

i want to write data in the cloud using the android app and read those data in the Texas Msp430, is it possible to do using azure system?
i dont know if it is better to use, in this case, just a cloud, iot hub on azure, or maybe a sql database, i will send some data from de android app to the micro controller through the internet.

thank you guys for any help!

Comment: There is no question here, just an appeal to general musings. While I can appreciate your wanting to reach out, SO is for rather specific technical questions.

Answer (score 0):

@AndreyViktorKandauroff, Your needs can be completely implemented via using Azure services. Per my experience, in my mind, there are two solutions below for the scenario.

1. Using Azure App Services. You can create an Azure App Service instance like Mobile App to handle the HTTP requests for writing data from Android App into Azure SQL Database or for retrieve data from Texas MSP430.

> ```
> Android App <---> App Services <---> Texas MSP430
>                        ^
>                        |
>                        V
>                     SQL Azure
> ```

2. Using Azure IoTHub if not need to store data, just for communication. You can use IoT REST APis to [send device-to-cloud message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt590784.aspx) from Android to IoTHub and [receive a cloud-to-device message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt590786.aspx) via polling on Texas MSP430.